# python Convert the date string of time zone abbreviation to timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone

I have many time zones abbreviation

```
{'CDT 05:00', 'CST', 'GMT+1 01:00', 'WAT 01:00', 'EST', 'EDT 04:00', 'WAT', 'GMT-5 05:00', 'UTC+00:00', 'GMT-4 04:00', 'GMT+9 09:00', 'MDT 06:00', 'GMT+2 02:00', 'GMT+04:00', 'GMT+01:00', 'GMT-7 07:00', 'AKST'}
```

I have a date string like `2023-07-20 07:10:00`. Now I want to make it to timestamp with all time zones I have one by one.
Just like below

```
timestamp = parse('2023-07-20 07:10:00','CDT 05:00')
timestamp = parse('2023-07-20 07:10:00','CST')
timestamp = parse('2023-07-20 07:10:00','GMT+1 01:00')
...
```

Any methods to parse the time zones abbreviation?

CST could be Central, China or Cuba Standard Time. If encounter this situation, just take the first one in the dictionary or give a custom option to choice

Comment: That’s a fairly random collection of notations, and some are ambiguous. CST could be Central, China or Cuba Standard Time. So you’ll probably have to have your own list of time zones and do the parsing and mapping yourself, if you don’t want to get random results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytz library to handle this

Here is a sample code:

```
# We need to import a couple of libraries first.
# pytz for handling timezones, datetime for date and time manipulations, 
# and dateutil's parse for converting string to date/time.
import pytz
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

# Here's a bunch of timezone abbreviations.
time_zones = {'CDT 05:00', 'CST', 'GMT+1 01:00', 'WAT 01:00', 'EST', 'EDT 04:00', 'WAT', 'GMT-5 05:00', 'UTC+00:00', 'GMT-4 04:00', 'GMT+9 09:00', 'MDT 06:00', 'GMT+2 02:00', 'GMT+04:00', 'GMT+01:00', 'GMT-7 07:00', 'AKST'}

# And here's a string representing a date and time that we want to convert.
date_string = '2023-07-20 07:10:00'

# Now let's go through each of these timezones one by one.
for tz_str in time_zones:
    try:
        # First, let's see if we can directly parse the timezone using the abbreviation.
        tz = pytz.timezone(tz_str.split()[0])
    except pytz.UnknownTimeZoneError:
        try:
            # If that doesn't work, let's see if we can use the GMT offset instead.
            offset_str = tz_str.split()[1]
            offset_hours = int(offset_str[:offset_str.find(':')])
            offset_minutes = int(offset_str[offset_str.find(':')+1:])

            # Create the timezone based on the offset.
            if offset_hours < 0:
                tz = pytz.FixedOffset(-60 * offset_hours + offset_minutes)
            else:
                tz = pytz.FixedOffset(60 * offset_hours + offset_minutes)
        except IndexError:
            # If we can't find an offset, then we can't do anything with this timezone. Let's skip it.
            print(f"Oops, couldn't figure out the offset for timezone {tz_str}. Let's skip this one.")
            continue

    # Now that we have the timezone, let's adjust the date and time for this timezone.
    naive_datetime = parse(date_string)
    localized_datetime = tz.localize(naive_datetime)

    # And finally, let's convert this to a UTC timestamp.
    timestamp = localized_datetime.timestamp()
    
    # We'll print the timestamp so we can see the results.
    print(f"Here's the timestamp for {tz_str}: {timestamp}")
```

This code you're looking at starts off by trying to figure out the timezone using the abbreviation provided. If it can't quite make sense of it, it goes, "No problem, let's try something different." It then tries to understand the timezone by checking the GMT offset in the string and uses that to create a timezone.

Once it's successfully got the timezone, it does a cool thing called "localizing" the date and time. What this means is, it tweaks the date and time to align with the timezone offset. Pretty neat, huh?

And we're not done yet! After the date and time have been localized, the code goes a step further and turns the localized date and time into a UTC timestamp. Just so you know, a UTC timestamp is in Coordinated Universal Time, which is a standard that doesn't budge an inch for daylight saving time.

But do remember, there are some time zone abbreviations that can be a bit tricky or might not even be recognized by pytz. For example, 'CDT' and 'MDT' are daylight-saving time zones, but pytz doesn't recognize these directly. So, for a safer bet, I would suggest using explicit time zone names, like 'America/Chicago', instead of 'CST' or 'CDT'.

Comment: That sounds very ChatGPTy, and is of course wrong in some details, and not even a complete solution to OPs question…

Comment: pytz.timezone will be always wrong